# Is involving myself in the Stack Overflow community considered an "Extra Curricular Activity"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm sending in an application for something recently.  One of the questions asked me for a list on what `Extra Curricular Activities` I commonly participated in.  After running through my day, I realized the I really enjoy reading and posting answers and question on Stack Overflow to improve my own abilities and to help others!

**So my question is**, would this count as an `Extra Curricular Activity`?

*I'm applying to NCSSM, an exclusive residential High School focused on Math & Science.*

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on who you're applying to really

Comment: @random Please check out my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if it's something you do outside your assigned school work, it's extracurricular activity.

Comment: All that 4channing will be a boon!

Comment: @random Make sure you post links to get credit!  :)