# Where do I ask a question about "how to use my participation on this site in college applications"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I participate on Math SE and to a lesser extent on MO and Physics SE. I'm starting to apply to colleges and was wondering where I should ask about how to list my participation on this site in a beneficial way.

I originally asked my question on `meta.math.stackexchange.com`, but it's been put on hold.
[Here's the question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21206/219489).
So which Stack Exchange site would that question be on topic?

I was half-hoping that the place is here, and Academia SE is for graduate students, and I'm in high school.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118095/is-involving-myself-in-the-stack-overflow-community-considered-an-extra-curricu http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261342/can-we-say-stack-overflow-a-professional-technical-society http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146613/does-your-so-account-get-a-mention-in-your-job-applications http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215495/what-can-stackexchange-do-for-me-professionally  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64416/can-stack-overflow-reputation-be-used-on-resumes

Comment: @random That looks like a yes. I consider 1,890 rep to be respectable.

Comment: asked and answered at TWP: [Should I include information about my reputation on professionally-relevant Stack Exchange (or other Q&A) sites on my resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/308/168)